# Dropdown menu for nav with this css

Tags: css, nav

So how do I make a dropdown menu using this css? Tried some tuts, but with this css I can't get any of those dropdowns working ;(.

CSS:

```
.main {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #171a21;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 6, 0, 0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 6, 0, 0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 6, 0, 0.45);
}
.main li {
    float: left;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 17px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    list-style:none;
}
.main p {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 17px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
.main a {
    display: block;
    color: #b8b6b4;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all linear 0.15s;
}
.main a:hover  {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm just starting with html&css and making a site.
Thanks for any help ;).

Comment: So many mistakes in the code, no presence of `<p>` tag, class name not written inside inverted commas

Comment: Check updated code in my answer, bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [**Fiddle:**](https://jsfiddle.net/d62k2444/3/)

The key is in those lines of CSS code:

```
.main li ul {
    display: none;
}
.main li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}
```

Should be quite self explicative.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make the dropdown look reasonably.
Test1, Test2, Test3 downwards?

Comment: Done a little fix and it look alright.
`.main li ul {
 position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding-left:0;
 margin-right:0px;
 margin-left:-21px;
}
.main li ul li {
    display: block;
 padding-left:16px;
 padding-right:16px;
    margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:-21px;
 background-color: #171a21;
 text-align: center;
}`

THANKS Mate!

Answer (score 1):

add these lines to your css file:

```
.main li ul {display: none;}
.main li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make the dropdown look reasonably. Test1, Test2, Test3 downwards sticked to eachother?